# How to plot class name from tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I took a function from the TensorFlow website to show a batch of images in my notebook. I want to print it the way it is shown on the [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) with the classes of the images above.
Here is the code of the function:

```
def show_batch(image_batch, label_batch):
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for n in range(25):
    ax = plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
    plt.imshow(image_batch[n])
    plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[label_batch[n]==1][0].title())
    plt.axis('off')
```

The problem is with plt.title... line. I receive the error: Cannot convert 1 to EagerTensor of dtype bool

I don't get what the problem is since I processed my data exactly how it was done in the website tutorial.

The label returns an array of shape: [False False  True False] and should print the class name (I have 4 classes) according to this. But it doesn't. The rest of the function works just fine but it is useless to show just images and not the names of the classes each image belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a beautiful way to do this, so I did it with an additional for-loop. I went through the label batch and saved the index with the true value.

```
def show_batch(image_batch, label_batch):
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for n in range(25):
    ax = plt.subplot(5,5,n+1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(image_batch[n]), cmap = 'gray')
    ix = 0
    for a in label_batch[n]:
        if a == 1:
            break;
        else:
            ix+=1
    plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[ix].title())
    plt.axis('off')
```

Just to make it more clear with example:

- the class_names are as follows **[class1, class2, class3, class4]**
- the label_batch is another array **[false, false, true, false]**
- in this case, the **right index is 2** (count starts from 0) and the class I need is **class3**.